# Is there a way to have my excel file open alongside the Mail Merge connected Word Doc?

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I want to automate my mail merge by simply adding a command button on the excel sheet that opens the mail merge word template. My problem is that if the excel file is open, the word doc won't connect to it, and vice versa.

Error is popping up "WORD ERROR HAS OCCURRED THE MICROSOFT ACCESS DATABASE ENGINE CANNOT OPEN OR WRITE TO THE FILE. IT IS ALREADY OPENED EXCLUSIVELY BY ANOTHER USER OR YOU NEED PERMISSION"

Is there an easy workaround that I'm missing? I don't know much about this process.

Here is the button's code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim objWord As Object

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True


objWord.Documents.Open "*word file path*"

End Sub
```

Comment: You have given too little code, and didn't put all the necessary key information. You said Excel, why is the error message showing ACCESS and how can anyone guess?

Comment: This is the only code I am using. It's a word doc set up for mail merge and a button that simply opens up that doc from the Excel spreadsheet. I have no clue as to why it says Access.

Comment: Then, that should be come from your file's data source, which could be Excel or Word. You should give us that example file to check out.

Comment: See *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* in the *Mailmerge Tips and Tricks* page at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html